# Trouble with first-page search result to install Docker on WSO2: WSO2 website links to "Dockerfiles" repository as an outdated version

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, docker, wsl2

This is a mistake of an absolute beginner. It might be a complete stupidity even. I just want to share it in case there is another absolute beginner out there.

I was asked to install Docker on Windows 10, and I did not expect any surprise, I simply searched for "wso2 windows docker" and clicked on a link of the official WSO2 website to reach "WSO2 Dockerfiles Documentation", thinking nothing can go wrong there: [Building Docker Images](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DF120/Building+Docker+Images).

Here is a full quote from the link:

> Step 1 - Obtain WSO2 Dockerfiles
>
> Use one of the following options to obtain the WSO2 Dockerfiles.
>
> - Option 1 - Clone the WSO2 Dockerfiles repository
>
>   Clone the WSO2 Dockerfiles repository and checkout the latest
>   release tag. You can find the latest release tag in the releases page
>   of WSO2 Dockerfiles repository.
>
> Cloning from WSO2 Dockerfiles Repository:
>
> ```
> isuru@isuru-ThinkPad:/tmp$ git clone https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles.git
> Cloning into 'dockerfiles'...
> remote: Counting objects: 2396, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (114/114), done.
> remote: Total 2396 (delta 60), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2282
> Receiving objects: 100% (2396/2396), 293.95 KiB | 54.00 KiB/s, done.
> Resolving deltas: 100% (1674/1674), done.
> Checking connectivity... done.
> isuru@isuru-ThinkPad:/tmp$ cd dockerfiles/
> isuru@isuru-ThinkPad:/tmp/dockerfiles$ git checkout tags/v1.2.0 -b v1.2.0
> Switched to a new branch 'v1.2.0'
> ```

I found that "the latest release tag in the releases page of WSO2 Dockerfiles repository" is [`v1.2.0` of 2016](https://github.com/wso2-attic/dockerfiles/releases). This cannot be right of course. How do I get the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link itself says it all, when clicking on "https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles.git", you get "https://github.com/wso2-attic/dockerfiles" instead, and this "attic" url can be explained with the first note in the readme.md:

> Note
>
> We have moved WSO2 Dockerfiles to separate product specific
> repositories and as a result this repository has been deprecated. WSO2
> Base Dockerfile, bash scripts for provisioning, Docker build, push,
> run, stop and entrypoint have been moved to [docker-common](https://github.com/wso2/docker-common) repository.
> Please find the new list of repositories [here](https://github.com/wso2?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=docker).

Confusingly, the official wso2 website is outdated, using a link to a deprecated repository. The answer to the question is: there is no later version of this repository than 2016. Instead, recommended guides are (and there surely are dozens more, this question was shared not for the guides, but for the trouble with that outdated link): [Get started with Docker remote containers on WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) or [Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/).